# Music Stops playing after scene change SKAudioNode Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

So I have been trying to get this audio file to play through all scenes of the game but it cuts off after the MenuScene. I call the `MenuScene` from `GameViewController`

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'MenuScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "MenuScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
```

Then in the MenuScene I start the music by doing this.

```
class MenuScene: SKScene {

var starfield:SKEmitterNode!

var newGameButtonNode:SKSpriteNode!
var difficultyButtonNode:SKSpriteNode!
var difficultyLabelNode:SKLabelNode!
var backgroundMusic:SKAudioNode!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {


    let backgroundMusic = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "Snap.mp3")
    backgroundMusic.autoplayLooped = true
    addChild(backgroundMusic)
```

The music starts playing. Then I have in the `touchesBegan ()` if the GameScene button is touched it will load that scene. I made the transition really long to find out when the music stops and it plays through the entire transition but when the `GameScene` is loaded it stops.

```
if nodesArray.first?.name == "newGameButton" {

            let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 5.0)

            run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 5.0), completion: {
                self.backgroundMusic = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "Snap.mp3")
                self.backgroundMusic.autoplayLooped = true
                self.addChild(self.backgroundMusic)
            })
            let gameScene = GameScene(size: self.size)

            self.view!.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
```

I want it to continue playing throughout the game and on the GameOver scene and loop over forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your in main SKScene and

You can do something like this:

```
self.runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("YourFileName.extension", waitForCompletion: false))
```

Repeat Music:

```
SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("YourFileName.extension", waitForCompletion: true))
```

Your music will keep on playing..

> With AVFoundation

One of my code I have done.

```
import AVFoundation


var backgroundMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

func playBackgroundMusic(filename: String) {
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(
filename, withExtension: nil)
if (url == nil) {
print("Could not find file: \(filename)")
return
}

var error: NSError? = nil
backgroundMusicPlayer = 
AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)
if backgroundMusicPlayer == nil {
print("Could not create audio player: \(error!)")
return
}

backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
 }

  import SpriteKit
```

Comment: how will I get it to repeat though, I did try this and it would play through each scene but only once.

Comment: I did put the line you added right under it and the song didn't repeat. I feel this is because my MenuScene is only called at the beginning of the game but the GameScene and GameOverScene call each other when the respected buttons are pressed. How can I get it to play in the MenuScene and repeat in the GameScene and GameOverScenes?

Comment: Try to put the first code in your MenuScene and then in your GameScene and GameOverScene put the second line of code. Let me know, if that works.

Comment: It still isn't repeating

Comment: I did try it out but the music still wasn't repeating.

Comment: See my updated answer. Try using it with AVFoundation in your SpriteKit Scene.

Comment: The line 

`backgroundMusicPlayer =
        AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)`

Keeps giving me this error: `SpaceGameReloaded/MenuScene.swift:27:9: Argument labels '(contentsOfURL:, error:)' do not match any available overloads`

Comment: I figured out how to get it work I just needed that one call in the very beginning of your post, however when I get a game over and start a new game it starts a whole new song overlapping the other one. Is there a way I check to see if the song is playing and if it isn't playing start playing that audio file?

Comment: you can do something like this: var isOtherAudioPlaying: Bool = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().isOtherAudioPlaying()

Comment: I am going to accept your answer I did something slightly different to solve my issue but your code did help be figure out how to solve the problem. Could I add what I did to your answer that helped me figure it out?